# Is the set of roots with respect to their values and multiplicies unique for each $g(x)$ in $a_n x^n + g(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I woke up and suddenly wondered about the following: A polynomial of degree $n$ $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n-n} x^{n-n}$ can be written as $a_n x^n + g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Then I was thinking that for every $g(x)$ has a unique set of roots with respect to their values and multiplicities - is this true?

So for instance consider a polynomial of degree $2$: $x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$ which can be written as $x^2 + g(x)$ where $h(x) = a_1 x + a_0$. Then *every* unique combination of $a_1$ and $a_0$ in $g(x)$ will give a unique set of roots in terms of values and multiplicities.

An example of this is $x^2 + 5x + 4$ (with $a_2 = 1$) - this polynomial has the roots $-4$ and $-1$, both with a multiplicity of $1$. Thus, for this $a_2$, only $g(x) = 5x + 4$ will give this set of roots. Only for a different $a_n$ a different $g(x)$ may yield this set of roots. I mean after all, any polynomial of degree $2$ can be written as $a_2(x - r_1)(x - r_2)$.

This is all something that I *think* could be true. So can any of you smart guys out there tell me if I am right and if so, might explain why this holds - that the set of roots with respect to their values and multiplicities are unique for each $g(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

Before proving that every unique combination of $\displaystyle [a_0,a_1\cdots a_{n-1}]$ makes a unique set of roots & multiplicities, you can (more easily) prove that each combination of $\displaystyle a_i$ has only ONE set of roots (not necessarily unique). Also prove that each set of roots only corresponds to ONE combination of $\displaystyle [a_0,a_1\cdots a_{n-1}]$. Then, combining results, you can prove that each $g(x)$ uniquely determines a set of roots and multiplicities.